# How to clone new array of objects by selecting particular properties from another?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, node.js, json

So,

I am receiving the data that has the following information:

```
{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "vote_count":22222,
         "id":299537,
         "ready":false,
      },
      {  
         "vote_count":2850,
         "id":299534,
         "ready":true,
      },
     ]
}
```

Now I need to make a new object that would contain the same structure but with **some** properties, ie:

```
{
  "data": [
   {
      "ready":false,
   },
   {
      "ready":true,
   }
 ]
}
```

I need the solution that is scalable, imagine having a set of data with 50 properties for example. Also, I did find solutions with objects, but never with array of objects.

Thanks guys, I've been busting my head for three hours now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [destrcuturing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) to create new objects like this:

```js
const input={"data":[{"vote_count":22222,"id":299537,"ready":false,},{"vote_count":2850,"id":299534,"ready":true,},]}

const data = input.data.map(({ ready }) => ({ ready }))

console.log({ data })
```

If you want to get a bunch of properties, you could create an array of properties you need. Then use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) or `reduce` to create a subset of each object like this:

```js
const input={"data":[{"vote_count":22222,"id":299537,"ready":false,},{"vote_count":2850,"id":299534,"ready":true,},]}

const properties = ["vote_count", "ready"]

const data = input.data.map(a => 
  Object.assign({}, ...properties.map(p => ({ [p]: a[p] })))
)

/* You could also use reduce like this:
  input.data.map(a => properties.reduce((r, p) => ({ ...r, [p]: a[p] }), {}))
*/

console.log({ data })
```

Comment: True, but that wouldn't be scalable. I would have to destructure 10 properties for example..

Comment: @JohnSam updated. You can create an array of properties you need

Answer (score 1):

Map the properties you want

```js
var obj1 = {  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "vote_count":22222,
         "id":299537,
         "ready":false,
      },
      {  
         "vote_count":2850,
         "id":299534,
         "ready":true,
      },
     ]
}
var obj2 = {}
obj2.date = obj1.data.map(data => ({ ready: data.ready}));
console.log(obj2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method and [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method

```js
const input = {
  "data": [{
      "vote_count": 22222,
      "id": 299537,
      "ready": false,
    },
    {
      "vote_count": 2850,
      "id": 299534,
      "ready": true,
    },
  ]
}
const extract = ['ready']

const data = input.data.map(o => extract.reduce((obj, k) => (obj[k] = o[k], obj), {}))

console.log({ data })
```